# UICollectionView Load image in the wrong position while scrolling Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

The problem is When is load the Application for the first time, for the delay  of connection the images load in the wrong position when the scroll the collection the images will change a few times until the scroll will end and the image will go back to the right image. I have no idea why this is happening. After the application is loaded the images take the correct position. I use Alamofire and Alamofire Image.

**Model Noticia:**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class Noticia: NSObject {
    //MARK: - Properties
    var name:String = ""
    var image:String = ""
    var number:Int = 0
    let photoCache = AutoPurgingImageCache(
        memoryCapacity: 100 * 1024 * 1024,
        preferredMemoryUsageAfterPurge: 60 * 1024 * 1024
    )

    override init() {

    }

    func setData(obj:JSON)->Noticia{
        self.name = obj["titulo"].stringValue
        self.image = obj["imagen_portada"].stringValue
        self.number = Int(obj["id"].stringValue)!
        return self
    }

    //MARK: - Image Caching

    func cacheImage(image: Image, urlString: String) {
        photoCache.addImage(image, withIdentifier: urlString)
    }

    func cachedImage(urlString: String) -> Image? {
        return photoCache.imageWithIdentifier(urlString)
    }

}
```

**ViewController**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NoticiaCell
    let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellBillboard", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BillboardCell
    //Billboard Cell
    if(indexPath.item == 0){
        cell2.contact = noticia[indexPath.item]
        return cell2
    }else{
        //Square News Cell
        cell.contact = noticia[indexPath.item]
        cell.layer.borderColor = ConstantProjectClass.colorBorderWebBizarro.CGColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = ConstantProjectClass.noticiasBorderWidth
        //Layout custom
        cell.setNeedsLayout()
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        return cell
    }

}
```

**Noticia Cell**

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class NoticiaCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    //MARK: - Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var labelView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topLabelConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var topImageConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    var imageUrlString:String?

    var contact:Noticia = Noticia(){
        didSet{
            self.labelView.text = self.contact.name

            imageUrlString = self.contact.image

            self.imageView.image = nil

            if let imageFromCache = self.contact.cachedImage(imageUrlString!){
                self.imageView.image = imageFromCache
                return
            }

            Alamofire.request(.GET, self.contact.image)
                .responseImage { response in
                    if let image = response.result.value {
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            let imageToCache = image
                            self.imageView.image = imageToCache
                            self.contact.cacheImage(imageToCache, urlString: self.contact.image)
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Any Help?

Comment: I would advise dodging trailing and bottom constraints in a collection view. Use leading and top constraints with a width constraint that has an outlet. Dynamically set the width and give an aspect ratio, or find another route.  [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517114/collection-view-cells-have-incorrect-content-size)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading several posts I found the solution:

**ViewController**

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NoticiaCell
        let cell2 = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellBillboard", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BillboardCell
        print("entro")
        //Billboard Cell
        if(indexPath.item == 0){
            cell2.contact = noticia[indexPath.item]
            return cell2
        }else{
            //Square News Cell
            cell.labelView.text = noticia[indexPath.item].name

            imageUrlString = noticia[indexPath.item].image

            cell.imageView.image = nil

            if let imageFromCache = noticia[indexPath.item].cachedImage(imageUrlString!){
                cell.imageView.image = imageFromCache

            }else{

                Alamofire.request(.GET, noticia[indexPath.item].image)
                    .responseImage { response in
                        if let image = response.result.value {
                            let imageToCache = image

                            if let updatedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NoticiaCell{
                                updatedCell.imageView.image = imageToCache
                            }

                            self.noticia[indexPath.item].cacheImage(imageToCache, urlString: self.noticia[indexPath.item].image)

                        }
                }
            }

            cell.layer.borderColor = ConstantProjectClass.colorBorderWebBizarro.CGColor
            cell.layer.borderWidth = ConstantProjectClass.noticiasBorderWidth
            //Layout custom
            cell.setNeedsLayout()
            cell.layoutIfNeeded()
            return cell

        }
    }
```

**The key is the following code:**

```
if let updatedCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? NoticiaCell{
    updatedCell.imageView.image = imageToCache
}
```