# what sort of control is recommended for this type of selection in swift 3?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, uicollectionview

I have attached the layout below and I want to know which control can be more flexible and appropriate in this regard.

[image]

Comment: Checkout [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38517114/collection-view-cells-have-incorrect-content-size). Your setup would be quite similar to mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely use `UICollectionView` control to solve this issue. Samll [example](https://www.raywenderlich.com/136161/uicollectionview-tutorial-reusable-views-selection-reordering) how it is possible to do this. In case of the `UICollectionView` it is easy to add new colors (`UICollectionViewCell`) and track selection of them and restore to required state. All required actions are implemented as methods of the `delegate` and `datasource`.